# Absolute div centered and responsive?

Tags: css

I have a popup div that needs to be centered and **width responsive** (fluid), but I'm using the common code with left 50% and negative margin left

```
width: 960px;
margin-left: -480px;    
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 50%;
z-index: 999;
```

but can I make it responsive, say if i want to have

```
max-width: 960px
```

instead of a absolute value?

**update**: maybe i wasn't clear but i don't see any relation with the question "Centering text vertically and horizontally in a div "

Comment: Same principle as aligning text

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On absolute elements, you can use

```
left: 0
right: 0
margin: 0 auto
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: argh i pressed -1 by mistake! your answer is perfect!!!! thanks!!! edit  your answer so i can give you +1

Comment: Just did, thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

Using transform:translate

**CSS**

```
width: 960px;  
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 50%;
transform:translateX{-50%}
z-index: 999
```

Comment: Webkit browsers have not needed a prefix for this in forever.

Comment: @rob they need on the mobile (safari, chrome).. have they made the changes in the last months? -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247808/css-transform-not-working-on-mobile  If so, thanks for you good news ;)

Comment: caniuse shows not needing it on 2D at all or 3D transforms going back to version 4 on Safari at least which is now at version 9.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.popupContainer{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  z-index:999;
}
.popup{
  background-color:#ccc;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popupContainer">
  <div class="popup">

  </div>
</div>
```

You could utilize [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this such as this codepen: https://codepen.io/andrasadam93/pen/YrrORq

```
.popupContainer{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  z-index:999;
}
.popup{
  background-color:#ccc;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}

<div class="popupContainer">
  <div class="popup">

  </div>
</div>
```